# Use eslint no-restricted-syntax to restrict library use

Tags: eslint

Would it be possible to using the eslint no-restricted-syntax rule to restrict the use of a library. For example, can the rule be used to restrict using the $.each method and if so, how?

Comment: Maybe `CallExpression[callee=MemberExpression[Identifier[name='$'], property=Identifier[name='each']]]`?

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me the following error message: Syntax error in selector "CallExpression[callee=MemberExpression[Identifier[name='$'], property=Identifier[name='each']]]" at position 38: Expected " ", "]" or
[^ [\],():#!=><~+.] but "[" found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now use the no-restricted-properties rules.

The correct syntax for no-restricted-syntax would be:

`MemberExpression[object.name='$'][property.name='each']`

Thank you platinumazure!